# алгоритм упаковки заказов в коробки (bin packing problem)

Tags: java, c#, python, kotlin

Кто-нибудь писал что-то похожее на алгоритм упаковки заказов в коробки. Корпус представляет собой таблицу со следующими столбцами: id, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ. Товар представляет собой таблицу со столбцами: id, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ. Заказ (строка заказа) - таблица: id, numberOfProducts, productId. На вход алгоритма приходит набор ящиков и набор ордеров. Вам необходимо упаковать самый лучший заказ и получить кейс, в котором он будет упакован, и положение товаров в кейсе. Написать модульные тесты, которые охватят алгоритм. Несколько советов, как это сделать на одном из (@Python @Kotlin @C# @Java) таких языков? Или у кого-нибудь есть следующий код или аналогичный? Вот такой пример из советов гугла или который первый в голову приходит ничем не помог (

```
MPVariable[][] x = new MPVariable[data.numItems][data.numBins];
for (int i = 0; i < data.numItems; ++i) {
for (int j = 0; j < data.numBins; ++j) {
    x[i][j] = solver.makeIntVar(0, 1, "");
}
}
MPVariable[] y = new MPVariable[data.numBins];
for (int j = 0; j < data.numBins; ++j) {
  y[j] = solver.makeIntVar(0, 1, "");
}
```

Буду Рад  любому совету!!!!

Comment: Задача линейного раскроя (а если у заказов есть веса - то о рюкзаке)... трёхмерная. Удачи, чё...

Comment: [Задача о рюкзаке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_рюкзаке) - NP-полная задача :(